# smoothness of function in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\phi$ be a smooth function which is $0$ outside the interval $[a,b]$, where $0<a<b$. We define a function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows. With $\phi$ as above we set :
$$h(x):=\Bigg(\int_{x}^{b}\phi (t)dt\Bigg)\Bigg(\int_{a}^{b}\phi (t)dt\Bigg)^{-1}$$
Then show that $h$ is smooth with $h(x)\leq 1$ for $x\leq a$ and $h(x)=0$ if $x\geq b$.

to prove this I have tried to used "Leibniz integral rule". But I am unable to get desire proof.

Comment: I think you should suppose $\phi \neq 0$ in $[a,b]$. Also, $h(x) = 1$ if $x \leqslant a$. Smoothness is a consequence of the fact an antiderivative of a smooth function is smooth. Moreover, the result is direct if you use the fact that $\int_x^b = \int_x^a + \int_a^b$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you only need to focus on the smoothness of the numerator, since the denominator hasn't terms that depends on $x.$ So, lets try to prove that $g(x)=\int_x^b \phi(t)dt$ is smooth.

Look first that $$g(x)=-\int_b^x \phi (t)dt.$$

Now, taking the first derivative, we have
$$ g'(x)=-\phi(x).$$
Now, could you follow this idea using the smoothness of $\phi$?

Comment: In your solution, I think in place of $a$ should be $b$ and could explain more? @rowcol

Comment: Thanks, I just edited that. Of course I could explain more; tell me what is not clear yet, please.

Comment: I have to use the smoothness of $\phi $? @rowcol

Comment: Yes, for example, $g''(x)=-\phi'(x), g'''(x)=-\phi''(x),$ and so on. In general, $g^{(k)}(x)=-\phi^{(k-1)}(x)$. And there's no problem about differentiability of $g$ because you have that $\phi$ is infinitely differentiable (smooth)

Comment: ok I got it thanks.